# Add a value to each line of a json string in the vuejs tree of components

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, vue.js

I have a Vue component that first generates an empty list like so:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        list: [],
        newThing: {
            body: '',
        },
    };
},
```

I fill this list with json data I get through ajax in the component methods like so:

```
//ajax call
    this.list = data.json();
```

I get an array with a bunch of objects as JSON like so:

```
[{"id":1,"body":"test body"},{"id":2,"body":"blablablabla"}]
```

### Now my question is:

I want to add one additional value to each of these values! Like so:

```
[{"id":1,"body":"test body", "editMode":false},{"id":2,"body":"blablablabla","editMode":false}]
```

So that I can work in functionality into my task app.
Does anyone have any idea how to best do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
this.list.forEach(function (obj) {
  obj.editMode = false;
});
```

Comment: I thought this was the most beautiful option!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.list = data.json();
for (var i=0;i<this.list.length;i++){
this.list[i].editMode=false;
}
```

Comment: You should add some commentary to help elaborate on what your code is doing

Answer (score 0):

`this.list.forEach(o => o.editMode = false)`

But only if you don't care about them being reactive. Otherwise you should use `Vue.set`

Answer (score 0):

Put your array in an variable and then iterate that variable and add accordingly.

```
<script>
var xyz =  [{"id":1,"body":"test body"},{"id":2,"body":"blablablabla"}];
$.each(xyz,function(i,data){
data['editMode'] = false;
})
</script>
```

Put this code Along with jquery library or you can write for loop in javascrpt you will get your desired output

Answer (score -1):

After the ajax call, it sounds like a simple `for` loop should work:

`for(var i = this.list.length; i--;){ 
     this.list[i].editMode=false;
}`

Comment: This code wouldn't even execute (missing semicolon). It's also one of the most confusing ways to structure such a for loop.